# Cast Replace when the initial string is dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `Preference` table. In that table is a `Section` column. For each entry in the table, the `Section` column will have multiple values separated by a single space. These values are operating system paths, and/or settings.

For instance `SELECT * FROM Preference' could return something like this:

`HomeDrive=C:\Windows\ ExternalDrive=D:\ Server=\\server\file\`

You will notice that the drives can be entered either as letter path, or as UNC path. The hard part is, that there could be settings anywhere in these entries. Another example:

`HomeDrive=C:\Windows\ UseHD=True ExternalDrive=D:\ Server=\\server\file\ FavoriteFolder=X`

I need to set these values, no matter what they are to my default set of values:

`HomeDrive=\\myserver\home`
`ExternalDrive=\\myserver\backup`
`Server=\\myserver\public`

I also have to leave all extra settings in this entry as they were, so changing the whole entry to my 3 sets of paths is not a possibility.

I would imagine I will use something like this:

```
UPDATE Preference
SET Preference= CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Preference AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'HomeDrive=\\?????\', 'HomeDrive=\\myserver\home') AS TEXT)
```

Because the original drive path is dynamic (Where my '?????' are in the query), I am not sure how to accomplish. The only definitive thing about each path is that:

- It will be either letter drive, or UNC
- Paths will always end in `\`
- It will be separated from the next value with a space

However, because drive paths can have any number of spaces, I am not sure if the space separator helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root of the problem is the way that these settings have be stored.  A relational database separates *distinct* pieces of data with columns, therefore each of these settings should either:

- Have it's own seperate column
- Appear in another table as a Setting-Value pair

How did this information end up in the database?  More importantly can it be seperated out **prior** to being inserted into `Section`?

You could also check out this [split function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str) for separating the values.

Comment: Unfortunately the data structure must remain the same, and the information can not be separated prior to being inserted.

Comment: @DanielHoerst - What are the reasons for this?

Comment: Because I am attempting to automate a task on a database of which I cannot control the schema. Fair enough?

Comment: In that case I think you should use a split function.  [See here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str) for details.  Although you'd likely want to add special characters to the settings so that spacers are no longer a problem.